# Calculate the memory size of training data

Tags: training-data, calculation

What do these parameters mean? i.e.(55000, 784)
How to calculate the memory size of train_features, train_labels, weights, and bias in bytes. Ignore memory for overhead, just calculate the memory required for the stored data.

train_features Shape: (55000, 784) Type: float32

train_labels Shape: (55000, 10) Type: float32

weights Shape: (784, 10) Type: float32

bias Shape: (10,) Type: float32

Answer (score 0):

Since float is 32 bit. 32 bit = 4 byte

```
train_features: 55000 * 784 * 4 = 172 480 000 bytes
train_labels Shape: 55000 * 10 * 4 = 2 200 000 bytes
weights Shape: 784 * 10 * 4 = 31 360 bytes
bias Shape: 10 * 4 = 40 bytes
```